# Parametrized Linq to SQL query causes performance issues

Tags: c#, sql-server-2005, linq-to-sql, sqlperformance, prepared-statement

I have a linq query that takes 11 minutes to execute against MSSQL server 2008. I used MSSQL Profiler to find the query taking so long to execute, and I ran it alone towards my database.

I also removed all parameters and added the values directly and ran the query. It took less then 1 second to execute!

I have googled and found that using parameters can really impact the performance because [the plan is compiled before the value of the where clause is known](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17033615/t-sql-select-from-view-much-slower-with-variable).

**Since Linq to SQL always run parametrized SQL, what can I do to improve performance in this case?**

I haven't found anything I can improve on columns regarding indexes. The first table in the Inner Join statement has 192 014 rows, and the SQL without parameters takes less than a second to execute. Screenshots of execution plans attached.

**Edits are below the screenshots.**

**This is the Linq query:**

```
var criteria = CreateBaseCriteria();

var wordsGroup = from word in QueryExecutor.GetSearchWords()
                 join searchEntry in QueryExecutor.GetReportData(criteria) on (word.SearchID + 100000000) equals searchEntry.EventId
                  group searchEntry by word.SearchWord into wg
                  select new SearchAggregate
                  {
                      Value = wg.Key,
                      FirstTime = wg.Min(l => l.EventTime),
                      LastTime = wg.Max(l => l.EventTime),
                      AverageHits = wg.Average(l => l.NumberOfHits.HasValue ? l.NumberOfHits.Value : 0),
                      Count = wg.Count()
                  };

return wordsGroup.OrderByDescending(w => w.Count).Take(maxRows);
```

[image: Execution plan of query with parameters (linq to sql)]
[image: Execution plan of query with known values]

Edit: The screenshots did go a little small in here. There are only 5 parameters in the parametrized SQL.

**Edit 2:** It is the Inner Join statement with parameter @p0 which causes the execution plan to change. When I only removed @p0 variable with the value itself, it runs in less then a second. If this value is constant in all cases (I have to investigate that) can I do anything so that this value doesn't get used like a parameter?

Comment: What if you turn it around: `word.SearchID equals (searchEntry.EventId - 100000000)`? The problem is that such expressions can't use indexes, but the other way around the amount of records to be scanned may decrease.

Comment: Turning it around changes the meaning and data returned. EventId is the value to look up in the other table, not EventId - 100000000. That is a completely different row...

Comment: Ohww.. OK. Anyway, that's the issue here. You've got so-called non-sargable expressions. You may have to create a mapping table that maps `word.SearchID` to `searchEntry.EventId` so you can join in an indexed way.

Comment: That might be a solution, but a much easier approach can be found in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to go around this statement, which is causing the execution time to just grow bigtime:

```
on (word.SearchID + 100000000) equals searchEntry.EventId
```

What I did was to add a [computed column](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191250%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) [SearchIdUnique]  AS ([SearchID]+(100000000)). Then I can change my Linq query to this:

```
on word.SearchIdUnique equals searchEntry.EventId
```

The query execution is down to less than a second, and issue solved.

Answer (score 0):

It is advising you to create an index in green colour above you query plan. Try this first.

Comment: As the execution plan is different for the two SQLs, and it doesn't advice to add any missing indexes on the one with parameters, how will this help in the version with parameters?

Comment: Adding the nonclustered index as proposed by SQL Server did not reduce the execution time of the query.